# How to extract the word which is follow by a specific word in regex

Tags: regex

I have the following sentence:

> education_level@187 criteria.either@190 education_level@192 in education_field@199 criteria.either@216 education_field@219 criteria.wider@222

I want to get the `criteria.either@190` words only if after `education_level@187`

Currently, my regex is the following:

```
(education_level@187)\s(criteria.*)
```

However, it extracts all of the string after `education_level@187` which is:

> criteria.either@190 education_level@192 in education_field@199 criteria.either@216 education_field@219 criteria.wider@222

Comment: "only if it is followed by" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by your description, because it sounds like what you described is the opposite of what you actually want.

Your current regular expression will get the word criteria and everything that follows it because of .*

If what you want is only the criteria sequence that follows education_level@187, then the following should select only that: `(education_level@187)\s(criteria.[a-z]+@[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `positive lookahead`. Something like this:

```
criteria.either@190\s(?=education_level@187)
```

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for a good explanation on `lookaround`.

Note depending on which host language you are using this is may or may not be supported. Check your language's documentation for details.